# Changed button style after SDK 13

Tags: android, button

My new game app was originally designed for a targetSDK of 13. I've since bumped it up, but my default buttons have changed in appearance. Not on the emulator, but on my actual Galaxy S3 phone, running 4.0.4.

The old buttons were rectangular with a translucent background and white letters. The new buttons look the same, but have an opaque, dark gray background. It happens for any targetSDK greater than 13.

Any ideas why, and how I can fix it? I'm not applying any specific style to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of googles new holo theme

The way to stop it from happening is to specifiy a theme in you manifest (right below the `android:name` and `android:label` attributes of your activity. Adding the following line will remove you

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme">
```

This should remove the holo theme, if it doesn't you can play around with some other themes until you find one which works. This might help - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html